# How to set up jQuery Guillotine Plugin?

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, editor

Aloha, I couldn't get the plugin to work. Here's my code, please help me:

```
    <html>
<head>
<script src="style/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> 
<link href="style/jquery.guillotine.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
<script src="style/jquery.guillotine.js"></script> 
<div id="theparent" style="width: 80%;">
  <img id="thepicture" src="http://www.iwallscreen.com/stock/ocean-wallpaper-desktop.jpg">
</div>
<script>
  var picture = $('#thepicture');  // Must be already loaded or cached!
picture.guillotine({width: 400, height: 300});
$('#rotate-left-button').click(function(){
  picture.guillotine('rotateLeft');
});

$('#zoom-in-button').click(function(){
  picture.guillotine('zoomIn');
});

 </script>
  </head>
</html>
```

Thnaks, Aloha :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly. This way you have to do in.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <title>Guillotine demo</title>
  <link href='../css/jquery.guillotine.css' media='all' rel='stylesheet'>
  <link href='demo.css' media='all' rel='stylesheet'>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, target-densitydpi=device-dpi'>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.js'></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
  <div id='content'>
    <h1>Guillotine demo</h1>

    <div class='frame'>
      <img id='sample_picture' src='http://lorempixel.com/640/480/city'>
    </div>

    <div id='controls'>
      <button id='rotate_left'  type='button' title='Rotate left'> &lt; </button>
      <button id='zoom_out'     type='button' title='Zoom out'> - </button>
      <button id='fit'          type='button' title='Fit image'> [ ]  </button>
      <button id='zoom_in'      type='button' title='Zoom in'> + </button>
      <button id='rotate_right' type='button' title='Rotate right'> &gt; </button>
    </div>

    <ul id='data'>
      <div class='column'>
        <li>x: <span id='x'></span></li>
        <li>y: <span id='y'></span></li>
      </div>
      <div class='column'>
        <li>width:  <span id='w'></span></li>
        <li>height: <span id='h'></span></li>
      </div>
      <div class='column'>
        <li>scale: <span id='scale'></span></li>
        <li>angle: <span id='angle'></span></li>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js'></script>
  <script src='../js/jquery.guillotine.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery(function() {
      var picture = $('#sample_picture');
      picture.on('load', function(){
        // Initialize plugin (with custom event)
        picture.guillotine({eventOnChange: 'guillotinechange'});
        // Display inital data
        var data = picture.guillotine('getData');
        for(var key in data) { $('#'+key).html(data[key]); }
        // Bind button actions
        $('#rotate_left').click(function(){ picture.guillotine('rotateLeft'); });
        $('#rotate_right').click(function(){ picture.guillotine('rotateRight'); });
        $('#fit').click(function(){ picture.guillotine('fit'); });
        $('#zoom_in').click(function(){ picture.guillotine('zoomIn'); });
        $('#zoom_out').click(function(){ picture.guillotine('zoomOut'); });
        // Update data on change
        picture.on('guillotinechange', function(ev, data, action) {
          data.scale = parseFloat(data.scale.toFixed(4));
          for(var k in data) { $('#'+k).html(data[k]); }
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Follow the setup section from this link [CLICK HERE](https://github.com/matiasgagliano/guillotine)

Comment: Have you initiated this into an Angular 2/4 application?

Answer (score 1):

The plugin doesn't add the control panel, you have to make it on your own according to what you need, and bind the the buttons to the actions.

At least in the example you provide you don't have any control panel, so it won't show up.

See line [22](//github.com/matiasgagliano/guillotine/blob/master/demo/index.html#L22) of the demo that comes with the plugin, there you'll see the definition of the control panel.